# Cannot find C# DataGridView HorizontalScrollBar property

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I use Visual Studio 2015 for a Windows Form project and want to hide the horizontal scroll bar, but not frozen. The reference of DataGridView shows a property "HorizontalScrollBar"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx

But I cannot find this property when I code with intellisense. I use 4.5.2 .Net Framework. If I set "ScrollBars = vertical", there is still blank area in the bottom, which I want to remove. Did anyone meet this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HorizontalScrollBar` is a protected property which is why it does not show in intellisense. You configure the scroll bars with the `ScrollBars` enumeration:

```
dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical; // or Horizontal, etc.
```

The blank area at the bottom is unrelated to horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough items in the DataGridView such that the vertical scroll bar is active?  I'm wondering if the blank area at the bottom is the background of the control when there isn't enough items to fill all the the grid. Could you add a screenshot to give a better idea of what you are talking about?  I would have expected `Scrollbars` set to `Vertical` to be the solution.